# Java NIO "No such device" Exception on linux but works when using FileUtils

Tags: java, nio

I am getting

```
java.io.IOException: No such device
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
```

When using this on linux (but works fine on windows):

```
    destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
```

But it works if I do this:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(processedFile,outputFile);
```

The source is a shared folder on another (Windows) machine.  This is also the case when it works on a Windows machine.

Comment: What NIO class/method are you using? How are `destination` and `source` being created?

Comment: They are created like this...

File outputFile = new File(path);
File processedFile = new File(path2);


FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(processedFile).getChannel();
                                FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(outputFile).getChannel();

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `FileUtils` is from Jakarta Commons IO, in which case it's a completely different implementation, so there's no correlation between them.

`FileChannel.transferFrom()` attempts to memory-map the portion of the file specified, and based on the error message, it appears that the problem is that the entire file can't be memory mapped. I would guess that your Linux box is running 32-bit, while the Windows box is running 64-bit.

Second option: looking at the manpages for `mmap`, this exception is thrown when "the underlying file system of the specified file does not support memory-mapping." How are you mounting the filesystem on Linux? If you're mounting a Samba filesystem, I could see why it couldn't be mapped.

Comment: They are both 64 bit machines.  But yes it is a Samba filesystem.  Does that mean there is no way of mapping it?

Comment: Googling for "mmap samba" turned up this: http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2008-March/058478.html which I think indicates that it's not supported. Additional Googling may give you more information.

Comment: As a general comment, although NIO promises performance boosts, I think you'll find that `FileUtils` does almost as well. The main performance drag in copying a file is disk/network access, not moving data around in memory.

Comment: parsifal - many thanks for your help.  I did google and around and did find that link you posted.  It wasn't very clear to me unfortunately.  I couldn't find much else.  

Re the performance boosts:  I googled that too and found that for the file sizes in question there was a signficant peformance boost.

Comment: @TGW - seems to me that slow and working is better than maybe fast but not working, but that's your decision. My personal experience says not to rely on Google searches for performance tips.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen exactly the same problem. Check if your share is mounted on Linux without `directio` option. In my case, remounting without `directio` immediately resolved this error.
 This option disables caching, but also disables mmap() system function.

When performing `mount` of a share, do not specify `-o directio`. Also check if the `/etc/fstab` file does not specify `directio` for your share.